# Invertibe matrix is a transition matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

It is true that all transition matrices are invertible, but does the converse hold: All invertible matrices are transition matrices?

I'm asking with regard to matrices over a field, but more general comments would also be welcome.

Sorry if this is a dup, but I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: I suspect the answer is yet.  However, if you want a thorough answer, you should clarify exactly what you mean by a "transition matrix".  If I have a matrix, how do I know it's a transition matrix?

Comment: Yes. By a transition matrix I mean a matrix which expresses a new basis for a vector space, in terms of a linear combination of the old basis. That is will all invertible linear operators preserve span and independence when applied to an arbitrary basis for the space?

Comment: Sorry, meant "yes", not "yet".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a transition matrix is a role, not a quality (like being invertible is). A transition matrix is a tool to convert expression of objects (vectors, linear operators) in coordinates with respect to one basis to expression with respect to another basis. Its columns consist of the coordinates of the vectors of one basis with respect to the other basis, and as such it is always square and invertible (the coordinates of the vectors of the other basis with respect to the first basis give the inverse matrix).

If you are asking whether any invertible matrix $M$ can figure as transition matrix, the answer is yes. Since the columns of$~M$ are linearly independent and of the same number as the dimension$~n$, they form a basis of$~K^n$. Then the vectors with coordinates with respect to a first basis $\mathcal E$ of any $n$-dimensional space$~V$ given by the columns of$~M$ will form another basis $\mathcal B$ of$~V$, and $M$ will be the transition matrix between $\mathcal E$ and $\mathcal B$.

Comment: Yes that was my question and that answers it perfectly thank you. So my mistake was thinking of transition matrices as a class of matrices rather than a particular use for invertible matrices. Correct? So then "all" invertible matrices in an $n$-dimensional space represent "all" possible bases for the space, with respect to their rows and columns?

Comment: @klib.so: Yes. If you fix an initial basis of a vector space, there is a bijection between the set of all bases of the same space and the set of invertible matrices, given by taking the transition matrix to that (other) basis.